# How to use a LINQ statement to get information from SharePoint

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2010

I am working on a little app to run some timer jobs in SharePoint.
Instead of just using a `foreach` to loop through all the jobs and pick the ones I want, I am attempting to select them by Guid via Linq statements.  However, I am not having much luck.
Here is what I have so far:

```
   foreach (SPService service in centralAdmin.Farm.Services)
{
   var traceJob =
       from jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions
       where jobDefinition.Id == traceGuid
       select jobDefinition;

   SPJobDefinition jobInfo = traceJob as SPJobDefinition
   Console.WriteLine(jobInfo.DisplayName);
 }
```

**EDIT** The error I am receiving is a "NullReferenceException" at `Console.WriteLine(jobInfo.DisplayName)`

I am sure I have just missed something since this is my first time using LINQ statements, but I have not been able to figure out what I did wrong.  I cast traceJob as `SPJobDefinition` because otherwise I cannot access any of the `SPJobDefinition` properties off of `traceJob`.  Any tips or pointers would be very much appreciated!

**EDIT**
the enumeration yields no results when searching for the Guid.
However, if I do the following code:

```
    foreach (SPJobDefinition jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions)
    {
     if (jobDefinition.Id == traceGuid)
     {
       jobDefinition.RunNow();
       Console.WriteLine(jobDefinition.DisplayName);
     }
    }
```

It will pull back exactly what I expect to see- the Job Definition's display name.  This would seem indicate that the issue is not with a faulty Guid or non-existent job.

Comment: Would be nice if you've provided exception message along with your question.

Comment: I apologize!  I just realized I completely forgot to add that in.  Will do momentarily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you're getting is because your `as` operation will always fail, and when an `as` fails it doesn't throw an exception, it just returns null.  The exception comes from using that null value.

`traceJob` shouldn't need to be cast at all.  Using `var` doesn't mean it's actually of a variable type, or even unknown at all.  It simply means that the compiler will look at the expression to the right of the `=` and use that (statically, at compile time) to determine the type of that variable.  In this case, hovering over `var` will show you that it is actually an `IEnumerable<SPJobDefinition>`.  What you have is a *sequence* of job definitions, not just a single one.  You can easily get the first item in the sequence through `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, or `SingleOrDefault`.  After doing that you'll have just one item, and you won't need to cast it at all.

```
var traceJob =
    (from jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions
    where jobDefinition.Id == traceGuid
    select jobDefinition)
    .SingleOrDefault();

if(traceJob != null)
    Console.WriteLine(traceJob.DisplayName);
```

Comment: This format appears to function correctly, however I am not quite sure why it failed until I added if `(traceJob != null)`.  Adding a final check shouldn't affect `traceJob's` actual value, right?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ returns an enumerator of results regardless that your query will always return at most one item. And since LINQ returns enumerator instead of actual results you have to *iterate* over it. Either by calling `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()` or any similar.

Try this statement instead:

```
SPJobDefinition jobInfo = traceJob.SingleOrDefault() ?? new SPJobDefinition();
```

Casting isn't required since your result objects are already of correct type. I also used *null coalescing* operator in case your LINQ statement doesn't return anything (job info doesn't exist). In this case `SingleOrDefault()` will return `null` because that's default for reference types.

You can of course omit null coalescing operation and check for `null` before using `jobInfo`.

Comment: I tried this, but for me at least, the nullref error remains.

Comment: Well then... Do you have a particular job definition with particular GUID? Because if you don't then it's no wonder that you're trying to access `DisplayName` of a null object instance.

Comment: Yes I do.  I can also access them just fine if I `foreach` through all of the job definitions so I know they exist.

Comment: @wjhguitarman: what is your debugger saying? If you ste a breakpoint at the `jobInfo` assignment and check the content of `traceJob` which will also iterate result set? Check what's inside and what values are on those objects.

Comment: @wjhguitarman: Ok so you see? Your LINQ returns no results. Aparently your GUID you're trying to get isn't there.